# Change order of elements in Rails association collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, collections, associations

If I have a collection of objects through a 'has and belongs to many' association in Rails (e.g.  the album 'summer photos'  has a collection of photos),  how can I arbitrarily change the order of the elements in that collection?  For example, there is a default index that would yield  @album.images[0] or .first.  how would I go about changing the collection, so that a another given image in that collection has the first spot? I think I can remove all the previous items from the collection, and then add them all back on, but that seems cumbersome, and not sure it really works even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[acts_as_list](http://github.com/rails/acts_as_list) is the standard way to do this.